# 'module' object has no attribute 'cut'

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to use the pandas "cut" method, but am getting an `object has no attribute` error. I've imported pandas and it works for other commands. Is this a known issue or am I missing something? I restarted Python thinking this might just be a random bug but it doesn't seem to be...

Full error below:

```
python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:08:41) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd 
>>> day1 = pd.read_csv('nyt1.csv') #<-- THIS WORKS
>>> pd.cut(day1.Age,[18,24,34,44,54,64,],right=False)[:30] #<-- THIS DOES NOT?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cut' 
>>> pd
<module 'pandas' from '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/__init__.pyc'> 
>>> pd.__version__
'0.7.0'
```

EDIT: Included the version of pandas.

Comment: what version of pandas are you running? Type `pd.__version__` to find out

Comment: Your version is quite old. I'm guessing it doesn't have the method `cut`. Try updating pandas.

Comment: Weird, I installed this using apt-get on Ubuntu, why would it install such an old package?? I'll upgrade and check again.

Comment: ubuntu repositories can often lag behind, or my understanding is, that if you are on an older version of unbuntu, often newer versions of packagaes are only available for latest ubuntu release. I'm fairly certain you can use easy_install in linux to upgrade python packages, but not being a linux user I'm not 100% of the ramifications of this!

Comment: @three_pineapples: Don't recommend `easy_install`. It's considered borderline deprecated; Python 3.4, 3.3.4, and 2.7.7 are all going to officially recommend using `pip`. Until then, see [Python Packaging User Guide](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/current.html) and [PEP 453](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0453/) for the same recommendation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cut` function was introduced in pandas [v0.8.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#v0-8-0-june-29-2012). Update to a newer version and your code should work!

Comment: That worked, thanks... Silly Ubuntu, now using `pip` as @abarnert suggested